# Robots.txt disallow duplicate product pages

Tags: robots.txt

I'm working with an e-commerce system at the moment that is throwing up hundreds of potential duplicate page URLs and trying to work out how to hide them via `robots.txt` until the developers are able to sort there ...... out.

I have managed to block most of them but got stuck on the last type so the question is:
I have 4 URLs to the same product page with the below structure, how do I block the first one but not the others.

1. `www.example.com/ProductPage`
2. `www.example.com/category/ProductPage`
3. `www.example.com/category/subcategory/ProductPage`
4. `www.example.com/category/subcategory/ProductPage/assessorypage`

So far the only idea I can come up with is using:

```
Disallow: /*?id=*/
```

this however blocks everything…

I believe I may have found a way to do it by setting up a `robots.txt` file to disallow all then just allow the specific paths I want again below that and then…once again disallow any specific paths after that.

Anyone know if this has a negative effect on SEO using disallow > allow > disallow.

Comment: Sorry I should of mentioned, every product has an ?id=number at the end of its url, hence the above disallow ive tried

Answer (score 2):

You could set the meta tag for the `rel="canonical"` property. This will help search engines know which url is the 'right' one and not have more than one URL per product in search results.

Read [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=en) for more information

Comment: Sadly not possible with the system at the moment, it is one of the things I have the developers working on along with sorting out the stupid URL structure.